# CSS - prevent text newlines from breaking flex alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have the following CSS, which allows me to create a row that wraps based on screen size. If there is enough space all items appear on one row, else it wraps to the next row with proper alignment.

My problem is that I have a description text under each "square" div. If this text is only one line there is no issue, but if this text is 2 or more lines, the square it is beneath gets pushed up and is no longer aligned with it's siblings. How can I prevent this? I've included example code as a snippet, it's easiest to open as a full screen view to see what I'm talking about. I want the tops of the squares to always be aligned

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.sub-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 300px;
}

.square {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #900;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="square">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-row">
        <p>
          Placeholder text Placeholder text Placeholder text Placeholder text Placeholder text
        </p>
        <p>
          00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="square">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-row">
        <p>
          Placeholder text
        </p>
        <p>
          00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="square">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-row">
        <p>
          Placeholder text
        </p>
        <p>
          00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="square">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-row">
        <p>
          Placeholder text
        </p>
        <p>
          00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've tried justifying the columns to flex-start and flex-end but that doesn't work. I've also messed with trying to use the align self property on the p element itself but I am unable to get the squares to be aligned if the text takes 2 or more lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `align-items: flex-start` to the `flex-row` (this overrides the *default* `stretch` behaviour).

Your *dyanmic text* being below the *squares* makes things easy as when the *flex items* wrap, the wrapping *flex lines* will will adjust to the height of the *dynamic text* in the preceeding *flex line*.

See demo below:

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* align-self: stretch;*/
  align-items: flex-start; /* ADDED */
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.sub-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 300px;
}

.square {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #900;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="square">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-row">
        <p>
          Placeholder text Placeholder text Placeholder text Placeholder text Placeholder text
        </p>
        <p>
          00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="square">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-row">
        <p>
          Placeholder text
        </p>
        <p>
          00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="square">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-row">
        <p>
          Placeholder text
        </p>
        <p>
          00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="square">
      </div>
      <div class="sub-row">
        <p>
          Placeholder text
        </p>
        <p>
          00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this seems obvious in hindsight but I am flex challenged, thank you so much this was giving me a headache. Question, why is the row still filling the width of the screen without align-self stretch? I thought I needed that to apply justify content properly, or at least like `width: 100%` or `flex: 1` or something

Comment: that's because your `square` and `sub-row` have a *defined* width, so they fill the row and then wrap...

Comment: but even with just one square rendered, the main row is filling the entire width of the screen. Even if I delete all the width properties and leave the single text node it is justified properly

Comment: with one square rendered, it is being justified across the row using `justify-content: space-evenly` that is being added to your flexbox...

Comment: Why are you terminating every statement you make with an ellipsis? It's my understanding that a flex container won't have full width unless it is specified so the `justify-content` property should be doing nothing, since the width is just the width of the contents. Clearly I am misunderstanding but you are not willing or able to help so I have no more questions for you, thanks for your answer

Comment: Hey man, it's past 12pm here and I'm too sleepy, I'm sorry if you felt I'm not helpful. A `display: flex` is a block-level element (theres  an `inline-flex` version too) If you have one flex item in a flexbox, it gets full-width of viewport to *flex itself*. And the *ellipsis* is a habit :)

Comment: you've been perfectly helpful, and even moreso with that explanation. I guess I have a habit of getting irritated by ellipses lol, no hard feelings